# How does `let` work in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I use `let` to create a temporary variable, and then use this temporary variable in the next statement. However, DrScheme complained,

```
let: bad syntax (not an identifier and expression for a binding) in: temp
```

This is my code snippet:

```
(define (case-one-helper str)
  (let (temp (substring str (+ 3 (string-contains str "my"))))
    (substring temp (string-contains temp " "))))
```

I wonder if the value of variable created by `let` has to be known at compiled time?

**Edit**
I've just figured out, missing `()`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While not exactly the problem you're experiencing, but an aside based on your questioning about the sequence of evaluating the arguments, `let` is also "syntactic sugar" for a lambda followed by it's arguments that are first evaluated and then passed to the lambda which is then evaluated.

For instance:

```
(let ((a (list 1 2 3))
      (b (list 4 5 6)))
     (cons a b))
```

is the same as:

```
((lambda (list-a list-b) (cons list-a list-b)) (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6))
```

So, if you're ever wondering about evaluation sequence, the arguments are evaluated fully before the body is evaluated (and one argument cannot refer to an argument preceding it ... use `let*` for something that requires bindings like that).

Comment: See "The Truth about Let" section in  https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch9/lambda.html

Comment: Interesting read ... looking over my answer here, I would say yes, and no, in the sense that `let` can be implemented as a lambda with an invocation of that lambda, but it's more than that.  If you write a scheme interpreter from scratch like in SICP, you'll see that `let` has a lot of book-keeping associated with it as you are naming the result of the expression.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put another set of parentheses around your `let` declarations:

```
(define (case-one-helper str)
  (let ((temp (substring str (+ 3 (string-contains str "my")))))
    (substring temp (string-contains temp " "))))
```