# let: bad syntax (not an identifier and expression for a binding) in: wordslist ###scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, let

```
(define (most-common-word str)
  (let (wordslist str-split str " ")))
```

I am trying to do a inner variable of lists of strings.
but I get the error "bad syntax".

I looked for answers here but the things I changed, didn't help.

str-split returns a list of strings with " " the separator.

thanks.

Comment: Have a look at "[3.9 Local Binding: let, let*, letrec, ...](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html)".

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: you have missing parens there.

Comment: [How to Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org); [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does \`let\` work in Scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766810/how-does-let-work-in-scheme)

Answer (score 3):

It should look like:

```
(let ([word-list <VALUE>]) <BODY>)
```

... which establishes a local binding from `word-list` to the value `<VALUE>`. This binding is effective only inside the `<BODY>` form enclosed by the `let`.

Now, in order to compute `<VALUE>`, you have to **call** `str-split` with the arguments you want (i.e. `str` and `" "`). The way you perform a function call is to wrap it in parenthesis (this is valid only in a context where the form is evaluated as an expression, not where parenthesis mean *binding*, for example). So `<VALUE>` should really be:

```
(str-split str " ")
```